# i want to send notification when receive a meesage in my chat app but it didn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

i tried method using firebase_messaging: 7.0.1 but now its firebase_messaging: 14.0.2.
i got this error :

> Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<String?>'

```
sendNotif(String? title, String? body, String? id) async {
  try {
    await http
        .post(
          Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'key=$serverToken',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(
            <String, dynamic>{
              'notification': <String, dynamic>{
                'body': body.toString(),
                'title': title.toString()
              },
              'priority': 'high',
              'data': <String, dynamic>{
                'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                'id': id.toString(),
              },
              'to': FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken(),
            },
          ),
        )
        .then((value) => (value) {
              print("send succeffuly");
            });
  } catch (e) {
    print("THe ERROR : $e");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()` returns a `Future<String>`, while the `post` API expects only current (non-Future) values.

The simplest fix is to await the value:

```
'to': await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken(),
```

Comment: what should i do then ?

Comment: Did you try the code change that I showed in my answer? What happened? Was there an error message after makign that change?

Comment: there is no error but i didnt get any notification. ps : am using onMessage method

Comment: So the change I proposed in my answer resolved the "Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<String?>'" error message that your question is about then?

Comment: Yea. Thanks for that. But now there is no error and i got notification only once and then it stopped but still showing no error

Comment: i still need help here

Comment: You posted a question about an error message in your code, and I answered showing how to solve that. Since that solved the error message, you now have a new problem with the delivery of messages through FCM. I recommend posting it as a new question, with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that troubleshooting message delivery is always something best done on the system where it occurs, so have a look here too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android